# Ayuda para hacer un For a un objeto Json

Tags: angularjs

Hola amigos tengo un objeto json con estos caracteres

```js
let json = [{
  "id": "1",
  "msg*": "hi",
  "tid*": "2013-05-05 23:35",
  "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "msg*": "there",
  "tid*": "2013-05-05 23:45",
  "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}]
```

quiero hacer un for donde quiero obtener solo el tid* pero me sale error al compilar en Angular alguna recomendacion?

```js
 for(let i = 0; i < this.json.length; i++){
             console.log(this.json[i].tid*)
        }
```

Comment: he hecho el mismo ejemplo tuyo, solo que definiendo la variable con var y no con let, esto funciona bien para mi sin tener que mapear el array ni los objetos, por que no intentas con eso y ves como te va

Answer (score 1):

Podés usar el método [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) de javascript, en donde recibe una función para recorrer el array y luego obtener dicho valor, por ejemplo:

```js
let json = [{
  "id": "1",
  "msg*": "hi",
  "tid*": "2013-05-05 23:35",
  "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "msg*": "there",
  "tid*": "2013-05-05 23:45",
  "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}]

json.map((v, k) => {
  var value = v["tid*"];
  console.log(value);
})
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me ayudo